# How to make grid layout responsive?

Tags: css, css-grid

learning responsive design with css grid. I have set some general layout for the desktop and that worked fine but I didn't manage to make the change for the phone. What I want to do is set all the pictures under each other. Any idea how to do that? I appreciate any help. You can find the snippet bellow.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.general-area{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
    margin:20px;
}



img[src$="jpg"] {
    width: 100%;
    height:250px;
    object-fit: cover;
   
    display: block;
}


.column1 {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    height: 0%;
   
    
}

.column2 {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    
}

.text {
    margin-right: 60%;
}

.text h1 {
    font-family: muli, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.column2 .cover,
.column1 .cover {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: muli, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
}

.dark {
    background-color: #0E4C92;
}

.light {
    background-color: #00B5FD;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    top: 8%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px gray;
}
.box-3{
    grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-column-end: 3;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
    .general-area{
        
        grid-template-columns:1fr;
        max-width:1200px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .text h1 {
        left: 0px;
    }
 
    img[src$="jpg"] {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        display: block;
    }
    .text {
        margin-right: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/dsl6sbt.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="text">
            <h1>Solutions for<br> medical<br> applications</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="general-area">
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src="Datový zdroj 2.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
                <a href="https://www.resinex.co.uk/contacts.html"><img src="Fluids.jpg" alt=""></img>
                </a>
                <div class="cover dark">
                    <h2>Fluids</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src="Datový zdroj 5.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
                <a href="https://www.resinex.co.uk/contacts.html"><img src="medical.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <div class="cover dark">
                    <h2>Medical device</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src="Datový zdroj 6.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
                <a href="https://www.resinex.co.uk/contacts.html"><img src="SurgicalTools.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <div class="cover dark">
                    <h2>Surgical tools and instruments</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src="Datový zdroj 1.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
                <a href="https://www.resinex.co.uk/contacts.html"><img src="DrugDevice.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <div class="cover light">
                    <h2>Drug delivery device</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src="Datový zdroj 1.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
                <a href="https://www.resinex.co.uk/contacts.html"><img src="Packaging.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <div class="cover light">
                    <h2>Packaging</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src="Datový zdroj 3.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
                <a href="https://www.resinex.co.uk/contacts.html"><img src="HomeCare.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <div class="cover light">
                    <h2>Home care</h2>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="column2 box-3">
                <img class="icon" src="Datový zdroj 4.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
                <a href="https://www.resinex.co.uk/contacts.html"><img src="Labware.jpg" alt=""></a>
               <div class="cover dark">
                    <h2>Labware</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just override the `display: grid` on `.general-area` class

```
@media (max-width: 720px){
  .general-area{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but from some reson, the .cover tag is now stretching out of the pictures